# Using C# , I am trying to loop through a 2D array with a for loop using a string array with names . Info does not appear when I compile

Tags: c#, loops

When I compile, the info from the array is not displayed. It will not show the name, phone number, or address. It will just come up blank. I followed many different examples using the for loop and I just can't get it to work, and there is no error message.

I appreciate anyone's input.

```
string[,] customers = { { "Jay" , "123 Fake Street" , "212 111 1111"},
{" Pete" , "123 Fake Rd", "212 222 2222" },
{ "Will" , "112 Fake Av" , "212 333 3333"}, };
string cusName,
cusInfo;
bool phoneNumberFound = true;

Write("Enter your phone #:")
cusInfo = Convert.ToString(ReadLine());

for (int row = 0; row < customers.GetLength(0); ++row)    
{
    // Retrieving the customers info from the array (second dimension of rows' width)
    for (int col = 0; col < customers.GetLength(1); ++col)   
    {
        if (phoneNumberFound)
        {
            cusInfo = customers[col, 0];

            WriteLine();
            WriteLine("Customer Name:\t", customers[row, col]);
            WriteLine("Address:\t", customers[row, col]);
            WriteLine("Phone Number:\t", customers[row, col]);
            WriteLine();
            //WriteLine("{0} , what size pizza do you want?:");
            ReadLine();
        }
        else
        {
            WriteLine("Your phone number was not found , please enter your name:\t");
            cusName = Convert.ToString(ReadLine());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: One thing I don't get is that you're reading the customer's input into `cusInfo` with `cusInfo = Convert.ToString(ReadLine());` and then clobbering it with `cusInfo = customers[col, 0];` and then never using it anyway.

Comment: `customers[col, 0]` uses col as the first rank, which is inconsistent with other uses. This is benign since cusInfo isn't used. The reason you are getting blank output is because your WriteLine statements are not using the specified arguments within the string.  You either mean `WriteLine("Customer Name:\t{0}", customers[row, col])` or `WriteLine("Customer Name:\t" + customers[row, col])`

Comment: what you want to achieve? Just printing details from 2D array. If that is the case check for the tutorials before posting an question https://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/csharp_multi_dimensional_arrays.htm

Comment: please provide more details on what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;

namespace TwoDArray_47478344
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            string[,] customers = { { "Jay", "123 Fake Street", "212 111 1111" }, { " Pete", "123 Fake Rd", "212 222 2222" }, { "Will", "112 Fake Av", "212 333 3333" } };
            string cusInfo;
            bool phoneNumberFound = false;

            Console.Write("Enter your phone #:");
            cusInfo = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());

            //loop through your customers
            for (int i = 0; i < customers.Length; i++)
            {
                if (customers[i,2].ToString() == cusInfo)//if you find a matching phone number
                {
                    Console.WriteLine();
                    Console.WriteLine("Customer Name:\t{0}", customers[i, 0]);
                    Console.WriteLine("Address:\t{0}", customers[i, 1]);
                    Console.WriteLine("Phone Number:\t{0}", customers[i, 2]);
                    Console.WriteLine();
                    Console.ReadLine();
                    phoneNumberFound = true;//set the trigger to true
                    break;//stop looping
                }
            }
            if (!phoneNumberFound)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Your phone number could not be found.");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here's an alternative way of doing it.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace TwoDArray_47478344
{
    class Program
    {
        public static List<CustomerInfo> CustomerList = new List<CustomerInfo>();//the list that will contain our customers(instead of the 2d array, I'm using a custom class).

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            MakeSomeCustomers();//populate the list of customers to cross-reference

            string cusProvidedInfo;//we'll use and re-use this to query the list of customers

            Console.Write("Enter your phone #:");//ask the user for phone
            cusProvidedInfo = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());//ask the user for phone

            CustomerInfo currentCustomer = CustomerList.Find(p => p.Phone == cusProvidedInfo);//check if the supplied phone number is in our list of customers

            if (currentCustomer == null)//if we don't have a customer, the phone number wasn't found, lets ask for first name
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\nCould not find you by phone number.\nPlease try entering your first name.");
                cusProvidedInfo = Console.ReadLine().Trim();
                currentCustomer = CustomerList.Find(p => p.Name == cusProvidedInfo);
            }

            if (currentCustomer == null)//well... we couldn't find the customer based on Phone number, nor based on first name
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Still can't find you. Looks like you'll have to sign up.");
            }
            else
            {
                //we did find the customer, we can show the customer info
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.WriteLine("Customer Name:\t{0}", currentCustomer.Name);
                Console.WriteLine("Address:\t{0}", currentCustomer.Address);
                Console.WriteLine("Phone Number:\t{0}", currentCustomer.Phone);
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
            Console.ReadLine();

        }


        /// <summary>
        /// just creating some customers to search against
        /// </summary>
        private static void MakeSomeCustomers()
        {
            CustomerList.Add(new TwoDArray_47478344.CustomerInfo { Name = "Jay", Address = "123 Fake Street", Phone = "212 111 1111" });
            CustomerList.Add(new TwoDArray_47478344.CustomerInfo { Name = "Pete", Address = "123 Fake Road", Phone = "212 222 2222" });
            CustomerList.Add(new TwoDArray_47478344.CustomerInfo { Name = "Will", Address = "123 Fake Av", Phone = "212 333 3333" });
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Instead of using a 2d array, I create a custom class to host the customer info
    /// </summary>
    public class CustomerInfo
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
        public string Phone { get; set; }
    }
}
```